# Is it possible / wise to work only with .TAB files in QGIS

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapinfo, tab

QGIS is great for it's ability to open and project almost anything I throw at it. I'm thinking of moving from Mapinfo 10.5 to QGIS, is it possible to just keep using the same .TAB files or would this limit certain features of QGIS or cause other problems?

The main reason I'd like to keep using the .TAB files is that other members of the office are sticking with MapInfo and I don't want to cause an office data schism.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tab files should be fine. From GDAL 2.0 onwards features can be updated and modified: http://www.gdal.org/drv_mitab.html

Mid/Mif files cannot be updated.

Answer (score 1):

You may have problems if you have .TAB files which contain two different feature types (e.g. lines and polygons). MapInfo allows this, but I don't think QGIS will.  I haven't actually tried this, so worth testing first. I use MapInfo and QGIS to good effect.